# if statement in success ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm having trouble implementing if statement in ajax success function.

```html
<?php  
  include('../Config/config.php');
  $myquery = "SELECT * FROM voters WHERE Precinct = '".$_POST['precinct']."'";
  $execute = mysqli_query($mysqli, $myquery);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($execute) >= 1)
  {
    echo "Precinct is full.\n Recheck precinct number.";
  }
?>
```

```js
function checkerprecinct() {
  var precinct = $("#precinct").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "precinctchecker.php",
    data: "precinct=" + precinct,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data === "") {
        alert("Data is empty!");
      } else {
        alert(data);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I would like to use this as a validation.
I want to alert the user if the sent data contains similar data from the database.

Comment: What happens with this code? Your `mysqli` usage is not secure, parameterize your query. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: what output on console?

Comment: What's the question here? What's the problem?

Comment: Have you checked what `data` is? It seems very unlikely to be an empty string.

Comment: Maybe you have new line return from PHP... `if (data.trim() === "") {` without an actual problem statement though the question is unanswerable.

Comment: What happens is everytime I type any keyword that doesn't have any records to the database , alert still prompting.

Comment: I want to get an alert only if my query num rows is more than or equal to 1.

Comment: currently which alert display?

Comment: user3783243 -- It works. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this code

change with your code

**PHP Code:**

```
$data = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($execute) >= 1)
{
    $data= array('code'=>100,'message'=>"Precinct is full.\n Recheck precinct number.");
    //echo "Precinct is full.\n Recheck precinct number.";
}else{
    $data= array('code'=>101,'message'=>"Data is empty!");
}

echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

**ajax code:**

```
var data = JSON.parse(data);
if (data['code'] == 100) {
    alert(data['message']);
}
```